# Difference between class instance method and generator

Tags: python, python-3.x

> You need to create a Bingo generator in which the size can be
> specified.
>
> ```
> bg = Bingo(size)
> ```
>
> Once created, every time a ball is taken out, the ball number must be
> provided, what are the balls that have been taken out since the start
> and how many balls are remaining.
>
> ```
> >>>> next(bg)
> >>>> (60, [60], 74)
> ```

I have the below class

```
class Bingo:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.initial_size = n
        self.current_ball = None
        self.picked_balls = []
        self.remainder_balls = n

    def pick_ball(self):
        # Do not consider the already picked balls for choosing randomly
        self.current_ball = \
            random.choice([i for i in range(1, self.initial_size)
                           if i not in self.picked_balls])
        self.picked_balls.append(self.current_ball)
        self.remainder_balls -= 1
```

In order to extract a ball from my Bingo, I would need to do the below:

```
bg = Bingo(100)
bg.pick_ball()
```

However, I have been asked to do it this way

```
bg = Bingo(100)
pick_ball(bg)
```

with a generator, so I was wondering if that was possible with the class itself or if it is a completely different approach. Any help will be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Literally, the *same exact function definition* will work, just put it outside the class

Comment: This requirement suggest that `pick_ball` should not be method of the class `Bingo` but stand-alone function that takes as argument instance of `Bingo` class.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for your prompt answer. Sorry, what do you mean by that? Could you please provide an example?

Comment: *Just move the definition of `pick_ball` outside the class*

Comment: @Guy you dont have to do that.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you don't *have* to, but `self` usually have very specific uses when working with classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an actual [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator) solution. I kept the requested name as-is, although it should normally be `bingo`.

```
import random

def Bingo(n):
    taken = []
    for _ in range(n):
        take = random.choice(list(set(range(1, n+1)) - set(taken)))
        taken.append(take)
        yield take, taken, n - len(taken)

bg = Bingo(75)
print(next(bg))
print(next(bg))
print(next(bg))
```

Sample output ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY5NC8IwDIbv/RU5NjgHQ0QRvPg3RGQfWVecael6cL@@dq0feDK3N3nyJHb2g@HN3roQ9N0a58HV3Jm7EB31cNKsjGQ8CIjl6xsxHOF8SbE3Dq6gedlQ9KHeZASzqmwHo1uSo568nMjLzFcF8KpChDUszSRHxB8Hl7W1xF2afkezprFLQJGxqIqakfilEaJR8X5@f7dFYZ1mL5keXjYK/@YQng)):

```
(19, [19], 74)
(30, [19, 30], 73)
(52, [19, 30, 52], 72)
```

The task description is not concerned about efficiency, but here comes an efficient one anyway. The above solution is already more efficient than yours, taking O(n) time for each pick instead of O(n<sup>2</sup>). The below solution takes only O(1):

```
def Bingo(n):
    remaining = list(range(1, n+1))
    taken = []
    while remaining:
        i = random.randrange(len(remaining))
        taken.append(remaining[i])
        remaining[i] = remaining[-1]
        remaining.pop()
        yield taken[-1], taken, len(remaining)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZDBDsIgDIbvPAVHiHPJYozGxIuvsezAsro1skKQRPf0E4YZGg/2Uv7y9W/BTn4wtDtaN884WuM8d4o6MzLWwZVfkHojSJ4YD@FgVEihxM9c492LgPYgqoLTppJyYby6AYX7ulnkY0ANuTH5xMDApEllTMlJA4mVfRuupqWyFqjLQI1NRj6r0XqV26r5hUprrMjNE4Lu0pTIF@lY8O99GGvjy9OfHPaSWYfkBcHTizau@0fP8ws)

Comment: You could tweak it to improve readability by yielding NamedTuples instead of tuples

Comment: @AlexWaygood Hmm, I guess I could. Would go against the problem statement, though, which shows a regular tuple. And I think it's unrelated to the question and would be distracting here. Maybe suggest that in an answer for their [codereview question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/268283/247591)?

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode this is a brilliant solution! One last question: in your first solution, is the set in set(range(1, n+1)) just to allow the intersection with the taken set?

Comment: @banana_99 Not intersection but difference, but yes, I build the set to allow that operation.

Comment: Thanks for all!

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode, fair. And, yeah, could do (hadn't realised it had been cross-posted...); but, on the other hand, there's probably only so much time one should spend on somebody else's bingo problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can make your class implement the iterator protocol and then use it in your function:

```
class Bingo:
    def __init__(self, n):
        # ...

    def __next__(self):
        if self.remainder_balls <= 0:
            raise StopIteration
        self.current_ball = # ...
        self.remainder_balls -= 1
        return self.current_ball

    # this is not strictly required for your use case, but makes 
    # it iterable as well, as in: `for ball in bingo:`
    def __iter__(self):  
        return self

def pick_ball(bingo):
    return next(bingo)
```

Comment: "this is not strictly required" it is, actually, if you want to implement the protocol correctly.

Comment: This is not a generator. It is a manual implementation of the iterator protocol. "Iterator" and "generator" are different concepts.

Comment: They added the "actual"/"original" problem statement, no need for the extra function but the results shall be more than just the new ball.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that "uses a generator and a class", as was requested in the question. It is a *little* pointless to combine the two in this way, however. For a more idiomatic class-based solution, you should probably prefer @schwobaseggl's answer (or use your existing solution); and for a more idiomatic generator-based solution, you should probably prefer @don'ttalkjustcode's answer.

```
import random 

class Bingo:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.start_size = size
        self.picked_balls = []
        self.unpicked_balls = set(range(1, (size + 1)))
        self.next_ball = self.bingo_pick_generator().__next__
        
    def bingo_pick_generator(self):
        unpicked_balls = self.unpicked_balls
        picked_balls = self.picked_balls
        
        for _ in range(self.start_size):
            new_ball = random.choice(list(unpicked_balls))
            picked_balls.append(new_ball)
            unpicked_balls.remove(new_ball)
            yield self

    @property
    def current_ball(self):
        try:
            return self.picked_balls[-1]
        except IndexError:
            return None

    @property
    def remaining_balls(self):
        return len(self.unpicked_balls)
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return (
            f'Bingo('
            f'start_size={self.start_size}, '
            f'remaining_balls={self.remaining_balls}, '
            f'picked_balls={self.picked_balls}, '
            f'current_ball={self.current_ball}'
            f')'
        )


def pick_ball(bingo_game):
    return bingo_game.next_ball()
```

Example usage in the interactive REPL:

```
>>> bg = Bingo(100)
>>> bg
Bingo(start_size=100, remaining_balls=100, picked_balls=[], current_ball=None)
>>> pick_ball(bg)
Bingo(start_size=100, remaining_balls=99, picked_balls=[50], current_ball=50)
>>> pick_ball(bg)
Bingo(start_size=100, remaining_balls=98, picked_balls=[50, 27], current_ball=27)
>>> pick_ball(bg)
Bingo(start_size=100, remaining_balls=97, picked_balls=[50, 27, 45], current_ball=45)
```